# Migrate Git Repo from one server to another server

Tags: git, migration, branch, gerrit

I need to migrate git repository from one server to another server. Our new git repository is created in Gerrit. I've cloned the repo from old server and tried the below things but it fails  to push the branches giving this error:

> error: unpack failed: error Java heap space)
>   fatal: Unpack error, check server log
>   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error)) error: failed to push some refs to url

**Migration steps tried:**

1. `git clone url`
2. `cd repo`
3. `git remote add neworigin Newrepo url`
4. `git push --all neworigin` (but it fails to push)
5. `git push -u neworigin` (fails)
6. `git push -f neworigin --all.` (fails)

Please suggest how to overcome the unpack issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java memory issue, you need to ask the Gerrit admins to increase the maximum heap size:

```
[container]
    heapLimit = 2g
```

More info: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#container

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried increasing the heap limit but it is throwing the same error.